# Where do packages installed/upgraded with APT get stored?

Tags: apt, package-management

As time goes by we tend to do apt-get install and add or replace software.

Are these archived in some form or do they get auto-cleared after installation? And if it doesn't get auto-cleared, it would mean that a clean up is needed, isn't it?

Finally, if they're not auto-removed, can we reuse these packages on different machines?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The downloaded packages are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

If you want to remove them, use `sudo apt-get clean`.

From `man apt-get`:

> **clean**
>
> clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package
>   files. It removes everything but the lock file from
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/. When
>   APT is used as a dselect(1) method, clean is run automatically. Those
>   who do not use dselect will likely want to run apt-get clean from time
>   to time to free up disk space.
>
> **autoclean**
>
> Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of
>   retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes
>   package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely
>   useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period
>   without it growing out of control. The configuration option
>   APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being erased
>   if it is set to off.

Comment: @Sergy thanks for that input. One more thing - can I copy the downloaded files and just rerun them on another computer? thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I never tried that but I think that just copying the files to `/var/cache/apt/archives` on another machine would allow you to install them without re-downloading (it would be better if they run the same distribution, of course). Alternatively, you can set up an NFS share from where all machines will install updates

Comment: "The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless"  Interesting!  I would have thought it was the ones that can no longer be downloaded that you might like to keep. :)

Comment: Yep, this is a bit confusing, but they're actually talking about old versions of software. After `foo-1.0.2` is released, `foo-1.0.1` is removed from the servers because nobody needs it anymore, when you type `sudo apt-get install foo` it'll download and install 1.0.2 *even if* 1.0.1 is in the cache. So, once it's removed from the servers, it is unlikely you'll ever need it

Comment: You can need it if the new one is broken, and you can force the install of a certain version (if it's still present on the server). Anyway debian has a website with all the versions of every package.

Comment: late to the party.  But @LtWorf. `Anyway debian has a website with all the versions of every package.` could you share the URL.

Comment: @samshers: I think for Ubuntu it's https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @samshers https://snapshot.debian.org/

Comment: @Sergey that doesn't have all the versions at all -_-