# How to remove configuration files of package without its reinstallation

Tags: 14.04, apt, uninstall, gnome-terminal, purge

I want to remove configuration files of a package (the system one at least), but avoid reinstalling the package because of its size. Basically I want to do this

```
sudo apt-get purge my-gigabyte-package
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get install my-gigabyte-package
```

but without reinstalling the package. I tried

```
sudo apt-get --purge install my-gigabyte-package
sudo apt-get --purge upgrade my-gigabyte-package
sudo apt-get --purge -f install my-gigabyte-package
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install my-gigabyte-package
sudo apt-get --purge check my-gigabyte-package
```

but as expected none of them worked.

Is there any option, how to achieve this?

Comment: Purge just removes/resets the packages config in `/etc` (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove). Note that it does remove the files in the user's home diretory, which most of the time are the issue. Which program(s) do you want 'purged'?

Comment: LibreOffice with a huge amount of extensions. I don't want to reinstall it because of that huge amount of extensions. I don't remember, where I found most of them, but I need 99% of them

Comment: `apt-get purge` with `-s` says 812 MB to be removed. With addition of `apt-get --purge autoremove` it could be more than 1 GB..

Comment: Why do you want to remove Libreoffice? If you want to remove you user's configuration of Libreoffice you can try moving/removing `~/.config/libreoffice` (or `~/.libreoffice` (can't remember)) to see if it does what you want. Note the packages might be cached (see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178806/where-do-packages-installed-upgraded-with-apt-get-stored) for where) so you might not have  - does the option `apt-get -s --reinstall install libreoffice*` (without `sudo`) show antyhing need be downloaded?

Comment: Sorry but there is a probably a easier way of fixing whatever your issue with Libreoffice is  than purging and reinstalling it.

Comment: I don't want to reinstall. And this is the only solution for my previuos problem in the another question there. Your option `apt-get -s --reinstall install libreoffice*` says multiple packages have broken dependencies. And without the asterisk `*` it says 33 new packages to be installed (I have fully updated system)

Comment: P.S.: The problem that requires reseting LibreOffice configuration files occured after upgrading to the 4.4.1 from 4.2.X through LibreOffice Fresh ppa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just backuped extension list and I'll make clean installation. But if there will be any better solution, please write it here for next generations. Thanks