# Where to find list of all audio packages in Ubuntu Studio Installer?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I mistakenly clicked install audio packages in Ubuntu Studio Installer, and even after cancelling, my apps menu is cluttered with a whole lot of junk apps.

Where can I find the full audio package list to delete them all please?

Comment: Have you tried running, `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt autoremove`? Also, `sudo apt purge ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-core` and then `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: Just be careful and review all the packages to remove before accepting or pressing Y to apply the changes. That is, make sure it's not going to install any packages you want to keep. Although, if it does uninstall any packages you want to keep, you can always take note of the package name and reinstall it afterwards.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/178806/where-do-packages-installed-upgraded-with-apt-get-stored  packages installed are cached on your system so you can check the filenames and purge those specific to "audio"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### First, run the following commands to uninstall the audio packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-core
sudo apt autoremove
```

This should uninstall the [meta]packages and autoremove should uninstall the dependencies that were automatically installed by the system.

##### Explanation:

So the following command will search for packages by the keyword "ubuntustudio" and filter the results to only list results that contain the word "audio":

```
apt-cache search ubuntustudio | grep -i audio
```

On 20.04, this returns 3 packages. `ubuntustudio-audio`, `ubuntustudio-audio-core`, and `ubuntustudio-audio-plugins`.

I left out the `ubuntustudio-audio-plugins` as they may be helpful although it will probably be removed as a dependency anyhow but in any case and if you still have packages remaining that you don't want, you can try to explicitly purge that as well:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntustudio-audio-plugins
sudo apt autoremove
```

##### I think at this point, your problem should be fixed but to more accurately answer your question (where to find the list):

The following commands will list the packages that these 3 packages depend on (the packages that are automatically installed):

```
apt-cache show ubuntustudio-audio | grep -i depends
apt-cache show ubuntustudio-audio-core | grep -i depends
apt-cache show ubuntustudio-audio-plugins | grep -i depends
```

The `apt-cache show` command lists detailed information about a package and here we filter only the line for dependencies, "depends".